# What is the difference between OFFLINE and ONLINE index rebuild in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, indexing

When rebuilding an index, there is an option for `ONLINE=OFF` and `ONLINE=ON`. I know that when `ONLINE` mode is on, it makes a copy of the index, switches new queries to utilizing it, and then rebuilds the original index, tracking changes using versioning to both (correct me if I am wrong).

But what does SQL do in OFFLINE mode?

Comment: For the record, you can use the ONLINE=ON option when adding new indexes as well, not just when you are rebuilding them.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In ONLINE mode the new index is built while the old index is accessible to reads and writes. any update on the old index will also get applied to the new index. An antimatter column is used to track possible conflicts between the updates and the rebuild (ie. delete of a row which was not yet copied). See [Online Index Operations](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/e/85eea4fa-b3bb-4426-97d0-7f7151b2011c/OnlineIndex.doc). When the process is completed the table is locked for a brief period and the new index replaces the old index. If the index contains LOB columns, ONLINE operations are not supported in SQL Server 2005/2008/R2.

In OFFLINE mode the table is locked upfront for any read or write, and then the new index gets built from the old index, while holding a lock on the table. No read or write operation is permitted on the table while the index is being rebuilt. Only when the operation is done is the lock on the table released and reads and writes are allowed again.

Note that in SQL Server 2012 the restriction on LOBs was lifted, see [Online Index Operations for indexes containing LOB columns](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/).

Comment: "If the index contains LOB columns, ONLINE operations are not supported in SQL Server 2005/2008/R2.". Question: will the REBUILD operation fail, or simply degrade to an OFFLINE REBUILD?

Comment: all indexes that contain LOB columns, or only clustered indexes?

Comment: Any index that contains a LOB column. Normally that is only the clustered index as LOBs are seldom included in non-clustered indexes.

Comment: See Appendix D in the linked white paper.

Comment: Does this apply top MySQL ON/OFFLINE index as well ?

Comment: @Adio MySQL is very different. Please reffer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html

Comment: Through experimentation, referencing Remus' very clear linked document, OFFLINE REBUILD performs a rebuild of ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA alright, with the page count being the same as before the operation, albeit, as he states, the allocation_unit _id and container_id change. REBUILD WITH ( ONLINE = ON ) changes things - no more ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA as it has been recombined with its IN_ROW_DATA.  My 3.5TB test DB had but 11 objects with ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA, 9 pages MAX(). Impact on REBUILD likely very low if typical, but in extreme cases, perhaps SUM() non-LOB containers for ONLINE space is warranted.

Answer (score 14):

The main differences are:

1) OFFLINE index rebuild is faster than ONLINE rebuild.

2) Extra disk space required during SQL Server online index rebuilds.

3) SQL Server locks acquired with SQL Server online index rebuilds.

- This schema modification lock blocks all other concurrent access to the table, but it is only held for a very short period of time while the old index is dropped and the statistics updated.

Answer (score 9):

Online index rebuilds are less intrusive when it comes to locking tables. Offline rebuilds cause heavy locking of tables which can cause significant blocking issues for things that are trying to access the database while the rebuild takes place.

"Table locks are applied for the duration of the index operation [during an offline rebuild]. An offline index operation that creates, rebuilds, or drops a clustered, spatial, or XML index, or rebuilds or drops a nonclustered index, acquires a Schema modification (Sch-M) lock on the table. This prevents all user access to the underlying table for the duration of the operation. An offline index operation that creates a nonclustered index acquires a Shared (S) lock on the table. This prevents updates to the underlying table but allows read operations, such as SELECT statements."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388(v=sql.110).aspx

Additionally online index rebuilds are a enterprise (or developer) version only feature.