# INSERT timeout during online index rebuild

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, indexing, command-timeout

Is there a way to prevent SQL INSERT timeouts during SQL Server index rebuild/reorganize operations? We are using NHibernate, command timeout set at 10 minutes, SQL Server 2008 R2, index rebuild is being done online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, no. Well, yes. If you do an online index rebuild then the table is still accessible. Requirement: ENTERPRISE edition.

[What is the difference between OFFLINE and ONLINE index rebuild in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309614/what-is-the-difference-between-offline-and-online-index-rebuild-in-sql-server) has more information on the difference and requirements.

Comment: But it *is* an online rebuild operation. Tables are still accessible, but insert times can get very large during these operations, resulting in timeouts.

Comment: Check resource governer - make sure you have enough IO budget set aside ;) Not sure what else to say - faster IO helps on the server. maybe your hard disc system is just way too small. Would not be the first such server I see.

Comment: It's a 6 disk RAID5 system, I don't think that upgrading is an option right now. But I hoped therr would be a way to throttle indexing a bit to prevent this.

Comment: 6 disc RAID5? You can also say "a 1 disc system" because this is exactly the write perfomance you get ;) Totally unsuitable for a non-trivial load database.

Comment: hm.. Now that you've mentioned it, it is probably RAID1+0 for the db actually. So, no throttling is possible?

Comment: Given that you already have enterprise edition (or no online rebuild) - check the resource governor. THrottling may / should be possible with that.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I checked, 4-disk RAID1+0 is used for the db (2x write speed, could have done better, but what the heck). We are using the good ol' [MaintenanceSolution](http://ola.hallengren.com/) script for indexing, which runs as CmdExec (sqlcmd) command, and since I have no experience with res. governor, I will need to google a bit to see how and where to use it.